# Neo4j graph academy - building neo4j applications with python - no .env file

Tags: python, terminal, neo4j, cypher

I'm doing the building Neo4j applications with Python course on Neo4j's GraphAcademy and am stuck early in the process with Setting Environment Variables. I've installed the dependencies (FLASK etc.) but don't seem to have an .env file for the next part...

> Setting Environment Variables

> This project will read environment variables from the .env file located in the project root.

> The project contains an example file at .env.example. You can run the following command in your terminal window to copy the example file to .env.

```
cp .env.example .env
```

But when I try to run this in the shell I get the following error:

```
cp: .env.example: No such file or directory
```

I don't seem to have a .env file in any of the newly created folders in the sandbox. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you sure you are in correct folder, quickly looking at the repo: https://github.com/neo4j-graphacademy/app-python you can see that the env example is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this worked:

Clone the git repository that provides the scaffolding

```bash
git clone https://github.com/neo4j-graphacademy/app-python.git
```

Change directory to be in the newly checked project root folder.
This step is not explicitly mentioned in the graph academy course.

```bash
cd app-python
```

Copy the template env file

```bash
cp .env.example .env
```

Inspect the file to make sure it looks right

```bash
cat .env
```

which printed

```
FLASK_APP=api
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_RUN_PORT=3000

NEO4J_URI=neo4j://localhost:7687
NEO4J_USERNAME=neo4j
NEO4J_PASSWORD=neo

JWT_SECRET=secret
SALT_ROUNDS=10
```

If you still can't get it to work, let me know which step fails and with which error.

Comment: Hi @Rouven B. the above works fine,  but when I try to do the next step: 'flask run', I get the following error:
 * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.

Comment: Ok, I did the following: 

"python -m flask run"

and it worked

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it answered your question.